# Typescript. wait a code to executing until a function finish executing

Tags: typescript

I have a code that calls a function as shown below:

```
this.getAllOptions(questionID);
console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
console.log(this.result);
```

the function is very simple, it calls a service that returns an array of object. From the returned data, I only need the "item.Content" in a string format, as shown below.

```
result: string;
getAllOptions(question_ID){

    this.result = "";

    this._service.getOptionsQuestion(question_ID)
        .subscribe( data => {
            data.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.Content);
            this.result += item.Content;
            });
        });
}
```

But the problem is, the codes after calling the function "getAllOptions()" get executed first.  I want the codes after calling the methods to wait until function done executing.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the data to arrive. Immediately after the call to `getOptionsQuestion` completes the observable created in `getOptionsQuestion` has not yet received any data so the callback you passed to `subscribe` has not been called yet.

There are several approaches to wait for the data, personally I prefer the async/await syntax in Typescript, makes for more readable code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as rsx from 'rxjs'

class Test {
    // Dummy service decalration
    _service : {
        getOptionsQuestion(nr: number): rsx.Observable<Array<{Content : string }>>
    }

    result: string;
    async getAllOptions(question_ID: number){

        this.result = "";
        const data = await this._service.getOptionsQuestion(question_ID).toPromise()

        data.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.Content);
            this.result += item.Content;
        });
    }
    async otherMethod (questionID : number){
        await this.getAllOptions(questionID);
        console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        console.log(this.result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also address the issue by returning a promise from the getAllOptions function.

```
result: string;

getAllOptions(question_ID): Promise<void>{
    let resolveRef;
    let rejectRef;

    //create a new promise. Save the resolve and reject reference
    let dataPromise: Promise<void> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolveRef = resolve;
        rejectRef = reject;
    });
    this.result = "";

    this._service.getOptionsQuestion(question_ID)
        .subscribe( (data: any) => {
            data.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.Content);
            this.result += item.Content;
            });
            // resolve the promise once result is populated
            resolveRef(null);
        });

    //return promise created.
    return dataPromise;
}


// execute the console logs on then part of the promise returned by getAllOptions
this.getAllOptions(questionID).then( () => {
    console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    console.log(this.result);
});
```